# what is the best practice for key names with keyExtractor for flatLists in reactNative?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

within the same component lets say we are rendering the following two flatLists:

```
const PROFILES = [
  {
    id: '1',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'John Smith',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    name: 'Jane Doe',
  },
];

const GROUPS = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'Group 1',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Group 2',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    title: 'Group 3',
  },
];

<FlatList
  data={PROFILES}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
    renderProfile(item, index)
  }
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
/>

<FlatList
  data={GROUPS}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => renderGroup(item, index)}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
/>
```

I'm setting the key per the react native documentation but my question is shouldn't there be a conflict?

PROFILE and GROUPS have objects that share the same id, which is being used to generate keys.

So for the first rendered item of PROFILES and GROUPS they share a key of value = '1'.

Wont this cause an error somewhere with react native?

isn't the purpose of a key to provide react native with a unique identifier so that changes made relating to that specific item only happen to it? With two items sharing the same key react native shouldn't be able to tell which item to apply changes to right? at least that's my understanding.

edit:

Wouldn't it be better to do something like this:

```
keyExtractor={(item) => `group_${item.id}`}
keyExtractor={(item) => `profile_${item.id}`}
```

:end edit

I never seem to run into an error related to this though and the docs don't seem to mention anything so I must be misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 0):

### Nice Question:

One thing Always Remember Each Child Should Specify Unique key means one object is different from another so it can use the same key.